# Trying to get Chatto Demo code working within my own app and getting asserting failure

Tags: ios, swift, chat

Trying to get Chatto Demo code working within my own app and getting an assertion failure.

https://github.com/badoo/Chatto/tree/master/ChattoApp/ChattoApp/Source

For the bare minimum I'm trying to return a TextMessagePresenterBuilder

```
  var presenterBuilders: [ChatItemType: [ChatItemPresenterBuilderProtocol]] {

    let textMessagePresenter = TextMessagePresenterBuilder(
      viewModelBuilder: textMessageViewModelBuilder,
      interactionHandler: GenericMessageHandler(baseHandler: baseMessageHandler)
    )

    textMessagePresenter.baseMessageStyle = BaseMessageCollectionViewCellAvatarStyle()

    return [
      DemoTextMessageModel.chatItemType: [textMessagePresenter]
    ]

  }
```

I am getting the assertion failure in heightForCell in BaseMessagePresenter

```
guard let decorationAttributes = decorationAttributes as? ChatItemDecorationAttributes else {
    assert(false, "Expecting decoration attributes")
    return 0
}
```

As far as I understand you don't have to use a decorator, and this code is straight from the demo. What am I missing?